# Formatting with str.rjust and variables

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables, justify

I am new to coding and this website, so please bear with me. I am working my way through "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python," and this is one of the chapter review questions. I am less concerned with solving the answer as to the strange behavior of the `.rjust` method. The goal of this project is to right-justify several lists of strings. To test my process I wrote a function to work on just one list.

My goal:

```
   apples
  oranges
 cherries
  bananas
```

Here is the code:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'bananas'],
                     ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
                     ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def test():
    for fruit in tableData[0]:
        longest = len(tableData[0][0])
        longestlen = len(fruit)
        if longest < len(fruit):
            longest = fruit
            longestlen = len(fruit)
        print(fruit.rjust(longestlen))

test()
```

I am trying to make the `.rjust` dynamic by referencing the longest string per list, but using the `"fruit.rjust(longestlen)"` prints the list without justifying it:

```
apples
oranges
cherries
bananas
```

If I swap `"longestlen"` with an `int` like say `8`, it works fine. Why can't I use a variable to define the justification, or am I doing something else wrong? I haven't found any documentation about this.

### Edit:

I realized I was adding extra variables to my code. It now reads as this:

```
def test():
    for fruit in tableData[0]:
        longest = len(tableData[0][0])
        if longest < len(fruit):
            longest = len(fruit)
        print(fruit.rjust(longest))

test()
```

This prints the same, unjustified output, but is cleaner.
I realize that this has the same issue with the value of my .rjust() = instead of > len(fruit), which causes problems with the .rjust method. However, if I do this:

```
print(fruit.rjust(longest + 1))
```

.rjust should work fine now that it has a greater arguement, correct? Yet it still does not justify to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rjust` has the same value as the length of string your trying to justify, due to that, you won't get any justifying:

```
print("foo".rjust(3))
foo
```

but:

```
print("foo".rjust(4))
 foo
```

So, in order to get this to work you *first* need to grab the maximum length and *then* justify:

```
def test():
    l = len(max(tableData[0], key=len))
    print(l)
    for fruit in tableData[0]:
        print(fruit.rjust(l))

test()
```

Here `l = len(max(tableData[0], key=len))` grabs the maximum value in `tableData[0]` according to the `key` (which is set to be its `len`) and then gets the `len` of that string (`cherries` is going to get returned so `len(cherries) == 8` will be used).

This now correctly prints out:

```
  apples
 oranges
cherries
 bananas
```

If you can't use `max`, you'll have to iterate through `tableData[0]` once to find the maximum and then loop again to print the values out justified.

Firstly, finding the maximum is done by setting an initial counter to `0` and incrementing it if a longer word is found:

```
longest = 0
for fruit in tableData[0]:
    if longest < len(fruit):
        longest = len(fruit)
```

after this loop finishes, `longest` will have the value `8`. Now, it is just a matter of looping through the list again and formatting, i.e:

```
for fruit in tableData[0]:
    print(fruit.rjust(longest))
```

Putting it all together in the `test` function, prints things out the way you need:

```
def test():
    longest = 0
    for fruit in tableData[0]:
        if longest < len(fruit):
            longest = len(fruit)
    for fruit in tableData[0]:
        print(fruit.rjust(longest))

test()
```

Comment: your answer does work, however the max() method is not introduced for a few more chapters in my book, so I am trying to use the tools I already know - even if I am trying to do essentially the same thing.

Comment: Fixed that for you @Apel. If you believe my answer answers your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick mark under the answer score :-) .